# Azure resource groups not deleting

Tags: wordpress, azure, resources, bitnami

I am having an issue when trying to delete a resource group as I get the following error in Azure;

Failed to delete resource group Default-Storage-EastUS: Deletion of resource

*group 'Default-Storage-EastUS' failed as resources with identifiers 'Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/bitnamieastusq5n61m4' could not be deleted. The provisioning state of the resource group will be rolled back. The tracking Id is '5b0424e2-bfea-4aef-a832-2230fb3bd279'. Please check audit logs for more details. (Code: ResourceGroupDeletionBlocked) Unable to delete storage account 'bitnamieastusq5n61m4': 'Storage account bitnamieastusq5n61m4 has some active image(s) and/or disk(s), e.g. bitnami-bitnami-wordpress-4.6.1-0-eastus-Q5N61m4. Ensure these image(s) and/or disk(s) are removed before deleting this storage account.'. (Code: StorageAccountOperationFailed)*

This was initially a Automated WordPress install from BITNAMI and linked to our pay as you go subscription.
On the BITNAMI account the VM has been removed completely, however it is still showing on AZURE.

[Bitnami/Azure resource screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAqtU.png)

Under Azure Portal, I have checked the Virtual Machines list and there is nothing present. 
I have also checked for any disks that may have not been removed correctly, but again there are none.
The delete process is:

1. Select Resource
2. choose the eclipse
3. select delete
4. enter the resource group name
5. Click Delete

Notifications show that it does start the deleting process, but then fails with the above error.

Has anyone come across this before, or have any suggestions on how to remove this resource completely?

I have also looked under the storage account on the portal and it shows bitnamieastusq5n61m4, however it will not delete either apparently due to existing disks, but where are these disks?????

The Portal does not show any images or disks....

[No VM Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgRZL.png)

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Azure says you cannot delete the storage account if it contains images/active vhd(s). In your case it is the same. So, before deleting the resource group you need to delete the image/active vhd(s).

Refer to the screenshot from - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/

[image]

I would recommend you to use powershell command with force parameter for the same.

```
Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "abc" -force
```